# jQuery sort using extra div classes

Tags: jquery, class, sorting

I have a WordPress site that displays a number of posts in a grid.  Some of these posts will contain an additional class in the first div of the block - either `.featured` or `.expired`.  I am trying to sort these after loading so that "featured" are listed first, and "expired" are listed last.  A sample of the divs:

```
<div class="search_results grid_style">
<div class="col-lg-3 itemdata itemid1012 item-1012 expired"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 itemdata itemid1013 item-1013"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 itemdata itemid1014 item-1014 featured"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 itemdata itemid1015 item-1015"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 itemdata itemid1016 item-1016"></div>
</div>
```

I have a similar function setting `equalheight` to these `divs` at document ready.  What would I need to add to, so the divs are also sorted as described above?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){equalheight('.grid_style .itemdata');  }, 2000); 
});  
</script>
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to send them sorted from server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and customize it as needed in WP (when you click expired, it reads all divs, sort them based on the existence of expired class and adds all back to the container):

```js
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#sortBnt').on('click', function () {
    var orderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    var x = 0, y =0;
    if($(a).hasClass('expired')) x = 3;
    if($(a).hasClass('featured')) x = -1;
    if($(b).hasClass('expired')) y = 3;
    if($(b).hasClass('featured')) y = -1;
    return x - y;
    });
    $("#container").html(orderedDivs);
});
```

```css
.box {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <button id="sortBnt">expired</button>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="box expired">
        <h1>B<h1>
        <h2>expired</h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <h1>A<h1>
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box expired">
        <h1>D<h1>
        <h2>expired</h2>  
      </div>
    
      <div class="box featured">
        <h1>C<h1>
        <h2>featured</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to sort expired to the end well enough.  How about the other half of my question - sorting "featured" to the top?  :)

Comment: Now when clicking, Featured is listed first.  (cool)
But Expired is listed 2nd and 4th instead of 3rd and fourth.  the proper final order in your example would be C A B D.
C= featured (first)
A= not featured or expired.  normal 
B= expired (last)
D= expired (last)

Comment: True, I made a mistake. now it works. I would advise using something like data-rank="some_value", not classes, and you could use data values directly in sort. You could virtually sort posts any way you wish.

Comment: After some tweaks, I got this to work for me.  Just so future readers know what had to get tweaked, here were my steps.  1) I had to adapt the classes to my originally posted code.  2) I had to change the function to `function ($)`   (Wordpress runs jQuery in compatibility mode). 3) placed the `var $divs = $("div.box");` line after the function call.  After all that, I am getting the expected results.